# Finding all possible paths

Tags: c#, recursion, traversal

I have a problem to find all possible paths.

> a a a b
>
> b a a a
>
> a b b a

Traveling from starting point at 0,0 to end point at 2,3. 
I need to get all possible paths.

Possible moves that I can do are **moving down** and **moving right**.

Let me tell you where I am stuck. 
I am trying to do with a recursive function . Starting with point at 0,0 and moving towards right whenever I can and moving down only when I must.

My recursive function :

```
public static move(int i,int j)
{
     if(possible(x,y+1))
    {
       move(x,y+1);
       move(x+1,y);
    }

}


public static bool possible(int i,int j)
        {
            if((i >=0 && i<3 ) && (j>=0 && j<4))
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
```

Not sure about my recursive move function. Still need to expand it . I am not getting exactly how I should implement .

I am able to traverse upto the corner node using that move method but I need that function to retrace back whenever all possible moves from the corner top right point(0,4) is reached.

Comment: You might consider posting the actual code because your move parameters don't match the body of the method.  What I'm seeing right now your move method moves down first but your comments state the desire to do the opposite.

Comment: I'm not rely sure why you need all the possible paths, would it not be better to just take the shortest path with for example using Dijkstra's algorithm instead. On larger problems finding all the paths will take a long time. Then just go back up and take the shortest path back.

Comment: Increasing 'y' coordinate means you are traveling right side, I guess.

Comment: I did a similar problem for shortest path using djkstra's . I need all possible paths now for this problem.

Comment: Replace the "possible" method with two methods CanMoveRight and CanMoveDown.

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: Tried replacing move with CanMoveright and CanMoveDown . if there is only one move from a point then I have to take that. But If there are two possible moves from a point . I need my program to take one path and retrace itself back to this point whenever the path is finished to traverse in another path. I need a function similar to this.

Comment: Expected Results: aaabaa, aaaaaa, aaaaba, ....

Comment: Dijkstra will give all possible paths you just need to save all the paths.

Answer (score 6):

You need to stop and take a big step back.

The first step should be coming up with the signature of the method.  What is the problem statement?

> Find all possible paths

Not mentioned: starting from a particular coordinate.

So the method needs to return a *set of paths*:

```
static Set<Path> AllPaths(Coordinate start) { /* a miracle happens */ }
```

OK, now we're getting somewhere; now it is clear what we need. We need a set of things, and we need a path, and we need coordinates.

What's a coordinate? a pair of integers:

```
struct Coordinate
{
  public int X { get; }
  public int Y { get; }
  public Coordinate(int x, int y) : this() 
  {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
  }
}
```

Done. So pop the stack; what is a path?  A path can be empty, or it can be a first step followed by a path:

```
sealed class Path 
{
  private Path() { }
  private Path(Coordinate first, Path rest)
  {
    this.first = first;
    this.rest = rest;
  }
  public static readonly Path Empty = new Path();
  private Coordinate first;
  private Path rest;
  public bool IsEmpty => this == Empty;
  public Coordinate First 
  { 
    get  
    {
      if (this.IsEmpty) throw new Exception("empty!");
      return first;
    }
  }
  public Path Rest
  {   
    get 
    {
      if (this.IsEmpty) throw new Exception("empty!");
      return rest;
    }
  }
  public Path Append(Coordinate c) => new Path(c, this);
  public IEnumerable<Coordinate> Coordinates()
  {
    var current = this;
    while(!current.IsEmpty)
    {
      yield return current;
      current = current.Rest;
    }
  }
}
```

Done.

Now you implement `Set<T>`.  You will need to have the operations "all items" and "union this set with another to produce a third". Make sure that sets are *immutable*. You don't want to change a set when you add new items to it; you want a different set. The same way you don't change 3 into 4 when you add 1; 3 and 4 are different numbers.

Now you have all the tools you need to actually solve the problem; now you can implement

```
static Set<Path> AllPaths(Coordinate start) 
{ 
   /* a miracle happens */ 
}
```

So how does this work?  Remember that all recursive functions have the same form:

- Solve the trivial case
- If we're not in a trivial case, reduce the problem to a smaller case, solve it recursively, and combine solutions.

So what is the trivial case?

```
static Set<Path> AllPaths(Coordinate start) 
{ 
   /* Trivial case: if the start coordinate is at the end already
      then the set consists of one empty path.  */
```

Implement that.

And what is the recursive case?

```
   /* Recursive case: if we're not at the end then either we can go
      right, go down, or both.  Solve the problem recursively for
      right and / or down, union the results together, and add the 
      current coordinate to the top of each path, and return the
      resulting set. */
```

Implement that.

The lessons here are:

- Make a list of all the nouns in the problem: set, path, coordinate, and so on.
- Make a type that represents each one. Keep it simple, and make sure you implement exactly the operations each type needs.
- Now that you have an abstraction implemented for each noun you can start designing algorithms that use the abstractions, with confidence that they will work.
- Remember the basic rules of recursion: solve the base case if you can; if not, solve the smaller recursive cases and combine the solutions.

Comment: Finally solved that problem. Although I did not read the entire answer of yours . Because I wanted to do it all by myself. But I did notice the word "Stack" and thankfully that saved me . :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MoveUp(Object sender, MoveEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanMoveUp(e.CurrentPosition.Y)) ...
    }
    public void MoveDown(Object sender, MoveEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanMoveDown(e.CurrentPosition.Y)) ...
    }
    public void MoveLeft(Object sender, MoveEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanMoveLeft(e.CurrentPosition.X)) ...
    }
    public void MoveRight(Object sender, MoveEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanMoveRight(e.CurrentPosition.X)) ...
    }
    private bool CanMoveUp(double y) => (y - 1) > 0;
    private bool CanMoveDown(double y) => (y + 1) < 4;
    private bool CanMoveLeft(double x) => (x - 1) > 0;
    private bool CanMoveRight(double x) => (x + 1) < 4;
```

These Values may not be right, but the code is reusable and easily maintainable in the event you would want to add any other possible barriers to movement you could easily add the additions to each method.

Comment: "reusable and easily maintainable" is questionable here, you've hardcoded both lengths of the array/matrix

Comment: I agree with you Mathias, however, These would best be constants or bound to whatever Data Source he is Working. I do not know the rest of his program design and this was not his question.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a 2D map or game as I have used similar matrices in the past for such 2D traversal through an array of Terrain objects, but again I do not know the context.

Comment: This is clearly a student project...reusable and easily maintainable is not germane.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard not to give away the farm and be helpful.  You should break down the decision logic to 3 boundary functions

```
inBoundsX x 
   // return true if x is in bounds, false otherwise

inBoundsY y
   // return true if y is in bounds, false otherwise

inBoundsXY x,y
  // return true if x and y are in bounds, false otherwise
```

Your recursive function should always validate the initial state it's given, then decide which way to move next.

```
move x,y
   if inBoundsXY x,y 
      print I am here x,y 
      // use InboundsX, InboundsY to decide next move.
```